# How to loop through multiple different text/conf files look for similarities and add extra information to an output file?

Tags: python, file

I'm a student assistant trying to complete an assignment for a colleague.

I have a .conf file with many thousands lines of code. I only need information from specific parts of the conf file. So to make it easier for myself i copied the 4 parts of the .conf file i need into 4 different .txt files.

The first file containing many different frontend uri's. I will not be allowed to show the exact lists I have for security reasons but it would look something like this: (with a space between each new uri)

```
/uri/data/something/documents/

/newuri/customer/business/

/somethinguri/anewone/hello

/hello/uri/common/
```

The second file containing same list of uri's with a new line under each uri with a string - either data1 or data0 (1 represents https and 0 represents http)- the file looks something like this:

```
/uri/data/something/documents/
data1

/newuri/customer/business/
data0

/somethinguri/anewone/hello
data1

/hello/uri/common/
data1
```

The third file containing same list of uri's with a new line under each uri that writes a host server address. The file looks something like this:

```
/uri/data/something/documents/
hostserver.host.org.com

/newuri/customer/business/
anewhost.server.com.net

/somethinguri/anewone/hello
thirdhost.test.server.com

/hello/uri/common/
fourthhost.server.test.net
```

The fourth file containing same list of uri's with a new line under each uri that tells me a backend uri. The list looks something like this:

```
/uri/data/something/documents/
data/backenduri/service/

/newuri/customer/business/
iam/a/backend/uri

/somethinguri/anewone/hello
backenduri/uri/service

/hello/uri/common/
data/backenduri/service/
```

I have been trying to create a script that loops through the first file saving each line (uri) into an array. Then going through the second file to look for each similar uri also with the string data1 or data0 being added to a new string. The new string would look like a uri plus the data 1/0 at the end of it. For example:

```
/somefrontenduri/uri/hellouri/ | data1
```

Then go through the third file containing the uri's plus the host server address. I would like to add the host server address to this new string. So it would look like:

```
/somefrontenduri/uri/hellouri/ | data1 | somehostserver.host.server
```

Then finally to the fourth file containing the long list of uri's as well as a backend uri corresponding to each frontend uri. I would like to add this backend uri to the final string so it would look something like:

```
/somefrontenduri/uri/hellouri/ | data1 | somehostserver.host.server | /somebackenduri/uribackend/uri
```

Keep in mind there might be a wild uri somewhere that is not in the other files, hence I can't just go line for line.

I don't really have any code as none of the things I have tried even come close to outcome I would like. The final result should be output to a new .txt file. How should this be solved?

Comment: You mention you want to program something, but you don't mention what programming (or scripting)-languages are at your disposal.

Comment: Can you show some code you've written? It would allow us to hook onto it with in the answers.

Comment: Also, you never say how you want to deal with issues where some URI is missing in either of the files

Comment: Hi, sorry for missing some information. I am trying to complete the assignment in Python. As to the issue where a random URI is missing that URI should just be 'forgotten about' or discarded in some way. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you always know there's just a single line of additional data, you can always get the line by index.

To deduplicate and check if a URI was already seen you can use a dict.

You can use this as a starting point for anything else. `agg` is used to aggregate all the data and should have items such as `{'/somefrontenduri/uri/hellouri/': [ 'data1', 'somehostserver.host.server', '/somebackenduri/uribackend/uri']}`

```
agg = {}

with open('file1') as f:
  lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]  # remove \n at the end

i = 0
while line < len(file1):
  agg[lines[i]] = []
  i += 2

def add_new_data(agg, filename): 
  with open('filename') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]  # remove \n at the end

  i = 0
  while line < len(file1):
    if lines[i] in agg:
      agg[lines[i]].append(lines[i + 1])
      i += 3

for filename in ('file2', 'file3', 'file4'):
  add_new_data(agg, filename)

for uri, data in agg.items():
  print(uri, *data, sep=' | ')
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking the time - this looks great! After reading the code I understand the idea behind it. I just tried the code in Visual Studio Code 'run and debug' but I seem to get syntax error at line 19: i += 3. I dont understand why it returns syntax error.. Invalid syntax. I am not able to test if it works. Obviously putting in correct file addresses in file1-4.

Comment: @Philip Syntax error you get is because I missed a `)` in the line above :D Fixed in the answer now.

Comment: @Philip if my answer helped, it would be nice to show your appreciation by upvoting/marking as best answer.